# How to detect if native FlashBlock is enabled in Chrome (and others)?

Tags: javascript, flash, plugins, google-chrome

Chrome has bundled a "native" flashblock for a while, as has the android browser. swfobject reports that the flash player is available, even if the block is enabled for all sites. All I want to do is detect that a user is using native flashblock, and provide some messaging. Certain services, like the Facebook JS SDK, do not work without flash enabled for cross-domain communication, and do not provide methods of detecting failure. I know how to detect an extension/plugin like the original flashblock, but the native version does not appear in the navigator.plugins list.

Is there a way to detect if a user is running with a native flashblock enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no programatic interface to the plugin-loading system in Chrome.

The best you can do is to load a flash object, and poll it via some well-defined method (`GetVariable("$version")` is the canonical example) to determine success. In the case you're concerned with, flash will show up in `navigator.plugins`, but won't successfully load your test plugin. It's really not a bad idea to do this sort of check anyway, as there are a number of reasons that flash might not load, above and beyond flash-blocking (native or otherwise).

Comment: I'd add that this sort of thing might be a reasonable feature request: http://new.crbug.com/ is the right place if you decide that it's something you'd like to ask for in a future version of Chrome.

Comment: I added it as a bug, and here's how I solved it, thanks to your answer: https://gist.github.com/981510. Thanks again!